# How to redirect to another page using a select menu and link_to - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I want to use a select menu to redirect to another page but when I select 'Home' it doesn't redirect me to the main page. Nothing happens...

```
<select>
    <option>Select a menu</option>
    <option><%= link_to 'Home', '/' %></option>
</select>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `link_to` helper outputs an HTML hyperlink which is not going to work when nested within an `option` element. You should change your options so that they have this format:

```
<option value="/">Home</option>
```

Then you could have some JavaScript that observes the `onchange` event of the dropdown and sets the `document.location.href` to the value of the selected option. This will perform the redirect.

Alternatively, you could have a *Go* submit button next to the dropdown that submits the form and then have Rails perform a server-side redirect to the page for the selected option using the `redirect_to` helper.

Comment: Thank you, I used the first solution (without submit button) with JQuery.

Answer (score 14):

You can't put a link inside a SELECT tag. This is a limitation of HTML, not Rails.

What you should do instead is something like this:

```
<%= select_tag(:menu_select, options_for_select([ 'Home', '/' ])) %>
```

Then you need to ensure that when the new link is selected, the page is loaded. This can be done with jQuery using something like this:

```
$('#menu_select').bind('change', function() { window.location.pathname = $(this).val() });
```

When the form selection is changed, the new URL is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

This will also work:

```
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="/">Home</option>
</select>
```