# Can navigate to route path directly, but not through clicking link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are the routes defined in my routes file:

```
#routes for colleges
get "colleges/universityofconnecticut"
get "colleges/ferrisstateuniversity" 

#routes for states
get "pages/connecticut"
get "pages/michigan"

#root route
root :to => "pages#home"
```

Here is a drop-down menu I have created. Note the use of routes:

```
<form>
<select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href= this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
  <option><%= link_to 'Connecticut', pages_connecticut_path %></option>
  <option> <%= link_to 'Michigan', pages_michigan_path %></option>
</select>
</form>
```

When I click on a drop-down link, the error I receive in the browser is "No route matches /Michigan" and "No route matches /Connecticut". However, I can type into my browser localhost:3000/pages/connecticut and it will work.

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Here is the result of 'rake routes'

```
colleges_universityofconnecticut GET /colleges/universityofconnecticut(.:format) {:controller=>"colleges", :action=>"universityofconnecticut"}
  colleges_ferrisstateuniversity GET /colleges/ferrisstateuniversity(.:format)   {:controller=>"colleges", :action=>"ferrisstateuniversity"}
               pages_connecticut GET /pages/connecticut(.:format)                {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"connecticut"}
       pages_michigan GET /pages/michigan(.:format)                   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"michigan"}
                        root     /(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
```

Comment: Could you paste the result of `rake routes`?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944977/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-a-select-menu-and-link-to-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Are you getting the capitalized "Connecticut" in your error? That seems weird. Could be something in your javascript for `on change` is grabbing the 'Connecticut' part of your link_to rather than the path. Can you post the actual browser HTML that you are getting for that form code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an `<a>` tag inside your `<option>` I believe. Inspect the HTML being output to the browser. The HTML should look like:

```
<option value="/pages/connecticut">Connecticut</option>
```

Your are probably getting something other than that. One solution is:

```
 <option value=<%= pages_connecticut_path %>>Connecticut</option>
```

This should create the correct HTML. There are probably some specific methods you can use in Rails that I haven't seen using `form_for` or `simple_form`. See also this:

[How to redirect to another page using a select menu and link_to - Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944977/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-a-select-menu-and-link-to-ruby-on-rails?lq=1)